# Compiles but doesn't print anything

Tags: arduino-uno

Here is my code. It is suppose to read a couple of sensors and print them out in the serial monitor. Any help please? Note that I'm new to object orientated programming.

```
/* The Blue Box

   Project description:
   Arduino black box flight data recorder
   This projects acts like a little homemade black box. It records data of a flying object.

   Details about the code:
   Altitude is calculated in meters above sea level.
   Records: day of the week, year, month, day, hour, minute, second, time from activation, yaw, pitch, roll, altitude, temperature

   This code is subject to a lot of ameliorations.

   By: xxx
   Date: 2016/08/28

   Extra credits:

   GY-521 library:
   I2Cdev device library code is placed under the MIT license
   Copyright (c) 2012 Jeff Rowberg
   https://github.com/jrowberg/i2cdevlib

   MPL3115A2 library
   Adafruit Industries
   https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_MPL3115A2_Library

   SD card library
   Code from example by Tom Igoe
   Included in the Arduino IDE itself

   DS3231 library
   Rinky-Dink Electronics
   http://www.rinkydinkelectronics.com/library.php?id=73
*/

#include <SPI.h>                        //include the SPI library
#include <SD.h>                         //include the SD card library
#include <Wire.h>                       //include I2C library
#include "I2Cdev.h"                     //include another I2C library
#include "Wire.h"                       //include another I2C library (yes, again)
#include "MPU6050_6Axis_MotionApps20.h" //include the MPU6050 library
#include "SparkFunMPL3115A2.h"          //include the MPL3115A2 library
#include <DS3231.h>                     //include the DS3231 library

//==================================================

#define testtest                    //*** COMMENT THIS LINE BEFORE UPLOADING OFFICIAL CODE TO FINAL PROJECT ***

#define chipSelect 10               //pin for the CS/SS
#define led 2                       //led and/or buzzer

volatile bool mpuInterrupt = false; //some random bool

bool ledState = false;              //state of the led and/or buzzer
bool dmpReady = false;              //state of the mpu6050

int yprInt[3];                      //gyro data in a integer because the extra precision of the float is total bullshit
int altitude;                       //altitude above takeoff point in meters
int altitudeCalibration;            //calibration for the altimeter
int temperature;                    //temperature in degrees Celcius

float counter = 0;                  //time counter, a somewhat internal clock that starts when the module starts dataloging

uint8_t mpuIntStatus;               //holds actual interrupt status byte from MPU
uint8_t devStatus;                  //return status after each device operation
uint8_t fifoBuffer[64];             //FIFO storage buffer

uint16_t packetSize;                //expected DMP packet size (default is 42 bytes)
uint16_t fifoCount;                 //count of all bytes currently in FIFO

String day;                         //day of the week
String ymd;                         //date: year,month,day
String hms;                         //time: hour,minute,second

MPU6050 mpu;                        //change mpu's adress
Quaternion q;                       //quaternion container
VectorFloat gravity;                //gravity vector

MPL3115A2 myPressure;               //MPL3115A2 object declaration as myPressure
DS3231  rtc(A0, A1);                //DS3231 object declaration as

void dmpDataReady() {
  mpuInterrupt = true;
}

class MainLoop
{

    unsigned long previousMillis;

  public:
    MainLoop()
    {
      rtc.begin();            //start DS3231

      Wire.begin();
      myPressure.begin();                                         //start MPL3115A2 communication
      myPressure.setModeAltimeter();
      myPressure.setOversampleRate(7);
      myPressure.enableEventFlags();
      altitudeCalibration = myPressure.readAltitude();            //read altitude

#if I2CDEV_IMPLEMENTATION == I2CDEV_ARDUINO_WIRE

      TWBR = 24;
#elif I2CDEV_IMPLEMENTATION == I2CDEV_BUILTIN_FASTWIRE

      Fastwire::setup(400, true);
#endif

      mpu.initialize();
      devStatus = mpu.dmpInitialize();
      mpu.setXGyroOffset(0);
      mpu.setYGyroOffset(0);
      mpu.setZGyroOffset(0);
      mpu.setZAccelOffset(0);

      if (devStatus == 0)
      {
        mpu.setDMPEnabled(true);
        attachInterrupt(0, dmpDataReady, RISING);
        mpuIntStatus = mpu.getIntStatus();
        dmpReady = true;
        packetSize = mpu.dmpGetFIFOPacketSize();
      }

#ifdef testtest

      Serial.begin(115200); //start serial communication
#endif

#ifndef testtest

      if (SD.begin()); ();       //sd card
#endif

    }

    void go(  )
    {
      unsigned long currentMillis = millis();

#if I2CDEV_IMPLEMENTATION == I2CDEV_ARDUINO_WIRE

      TWBR = 24;

#elif I2CDEV_IMPLEMENTATION == I2CDEV_BUILTIN_FASTWIRE

      Fastwire::setup(400, true);
#endif

      mpu.initialize();
      devStatus = mpu.dmpInitialize();
      mpu.setXGyroOffset(0);
      mpu.setYGyroOffset(0);
      mpu.setZGyroOffset(0);
      mpu.setZAccelOffset(0);

      if (devStatus == 0)
      {
        mpu.setDMPEnabled(true);
        attachInterrupt(0, dmpDataReady, RISING);
        mpuIntStatus = mpu.getIntStatus();
        dmpReady = true;
        packetSize = mpu.dmpGetFIFOPacketSize();
      }

      else
      {
        return;
      }

      altitude = myPressure.readAltitude() - altitudeCalibration; //read altitude
      temperature = myPressure.readTemp();                        //read temperature


      day = rtc.getDOWStr();  //get day of the week
      ymd = rtc.getDateStr(); //get day, month, year
      hms = rtc.getTimeStr(); //get hour, minutes, seconds

#ifdef testtest

      Serial.print(day);
      Serial.print(" ");
      Serial.print(ymd);
      Serial.print(" -- ");
      Serial.print(hms);
      Serial.print(", ");
      Serial.print(counter);
      Serial.print(", ");
      Serial.print(yprInt[0]);
      Serial.print(", ");
      Serial.print(yprInt[1]);
      Serial.print(", ");
      Serial.print(yprInt[2]);
      Serial.print(", ");
      Serial.print(altitude);
      Serial.print(" ,");
      Serial.print(temperature);
      Serial.println();
#endif

#ifndef testtest

      if (altitude > 1) //if the device is higher then 1m, then we sstart recording everything
      {
        File dataFile = SD.open("datalog.txt", FILE_WRITE);

        if (dataFile)
        {
          dataFile.print(day);
          dataFile.print(" ");
          dataFile.print(ymd);
          dataFile.print(" -- ");
          dataFile.print(hms);
          dataFile.print(", ");
          dataFile.print(counter);
          dataFile.print(", ");
          dataFile.print(yprInt[0]);
          dataFile.print(", ");
          dataFile.print(yprInt[1]);
          dataFile.print(", ");
          dataFile.print(yprInt[2]);
          dataFile.print(", ");
          dataFile.print(altitude);
          dataFile.print(" ,");
          dataFile.print(temperature);
          dataFile.println();
          dataFile.close();
        }
      }
#endif

      counter = counter + 0.5;

    }
};

MainLoop main;

void setup() {
}

void loop()  {
  main.go();
}
```

Comment: Why are you using a class in the first place?

Comment: Save a bit of memory and trying to learn new things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move all that code out of the constructor and put it in a `.begin()` method to call from `setup()`. You are calling functions before the chip has been initialized and things are being undone.

It is only safe to use a constructor to initialize a few variables and the like. Simply because the call sequence is:

1. Constructors
2. System Init
3. Setup
4. Repeat forever:
5. -> Loop

System Init configures the timers, peripherals, IO pins, etc. Things which need to be done *before* the code in your constructor.

Comment: mind giving a small example. im really not familiar with class and constructors...

Comment: Just rename your constructor to `void begin()` and then call `main.begin()` in `setup()`. Incidentally, calling it `main` is not good since that could cripple the `main()` function. Call it `myMain` instead.

Comment: `im really not familiar with class and constructors` - when an *instance* of a class is created its constructor (if it has one) is called to do preliminary housework. The constructor is a function with the same name as the class (in your case: `MainLoop`). On the Arduino it is not useful or safe to do much in a constructor other than setting variables (eg. setting them to zero).

Comment: You might also want to learn about the [Static Initialization Order Fiasco](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order) problem in C++. A good example is using `Serial` in your own statically initialized class constructor (as you attempted). Which comes first - the `Serial` or `MainLoop` constructor...? Who knows...?

Answer (score 1):

> mind giving a small example. I'm really not familiar with class and constructors

Here is an example of trying to do things in the constructor:

```
class foo 
{
  public:
  foo () // constructor
    {
    Serial.begin (115200);
    Serial.println ("Hello, world.");
    }
}; // end of class foo

foo bar;  // make an instance of foo

void setup() { }
void loop() { }
```

On my setup that prints "Hel" and nothing else.

---

Now if we change things around it works:

```
class foo 
{
  public:
  void begin ()
    {
    Serial.begin (115200);
    Serial.println ("Hello, world.");
    }
}; // end of class foo

foo bar;  // make an instance of foo

void setup() 
  {
  bar.begin ();
  }

void loop() { }
```

Now we are doing things in the right order. "Under the hood" the `main` function provided by the IDE initializes the hardware (by calling `init`) and then calls `setup`. Now we can call the `begin` function in our class.

---

It would have worked if we created the class instance inside `setup` because that is after `init` is called, like this:

```
class foo 
{
  public:
  foo () // constructor
    {
    Serial.begin (115200);
    Serial.println ("Hello, world.");
    }
}; // end of class foo


void setup() 
  { 
  foo bar;  // make an instance of foo
  }

void loop() { }
```

However now `bar` is not a global variable.

---

What is sometimes done is to make a function to return an instance of the class, which creates it the first time it is called, like this:

```
class foo 
{
  public:
  foo () // constructor
    {
    Serial.println (F("Hello, world."));
    }
  void doSomething ()
    {
    Serial.println (F("Doing something"));
    }
}; // end of class foo

foo & getFoo ()
  {
  static foo myBar;  // make an instance of foo
  return myBar;
  }  // end of getFoo

void setup() 
  { 
  Serial.begin (115200);
  Serial.println (F("Program starting."));

  foo & bar = getFoo ();
  bar.doSomething ();
  }  // end of setup

void loop() 
  { 
  foo & bar = getFoo ();
  bar.doSomething ();
  delay (500);
  }  // end of loop
```

Now the function `getFoo` returns a *reference* to the instance of foo created as a static variable inside it. Thus, *the first time it is called*, the instance is created. Subsequent times just return the same instance.